# Pandas ploting histogram

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is the following:

```
month category hours
1, A, 5
1, B, 8
1, C, 2
2, A, 4
2, B, 9
2, C, 5
...
12, A, 10
12, B, 2
12, C, 4
```

I want to plot a histogram using Python pandas plugin where the y axis is the sum of all the hours of all categories in a certain month and the x axis is the month.

How can I do that?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried df.plot.hist(by='month')

Comment: And what is the result? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` and then `plot`:

```
df.groupby('month')['hours'].sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

Output:

[image]